# How to filter by sub-aggregated results in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I've got the following elastic search query in order to get the number of product sales per hour grouped by product id and hour of sale.

```
POST /my_sales/_search?size=0
{
  "aggs": {
    "sales_per_hour": {
      "date_histogram": {
        "field": "event_time",
        "fixed_interval": "1h",
        "format": "yyyy-MM-dd:HH:mm"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "sales_per_hour_per_product": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "name.keyword"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

One example of data :

```
{
    "@timestamp" : "2020-10-29T18:09:56.921Z",
    "name" : "my-beautifull_product",
    "event_time" : "2020-10-17T08:01:33.397Z"
}
```

This query returns several buckets (one per hour and per product) but i would like to only retrieve those who have a doc_count higher than 10 for example, is it possible ?
For those results i would like to know the id of the product and the event_time bucket.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Perhaps the answer is to use "min_doc_count" but with this solution I also get empty buckets ?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps using the [Bucket Selector](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-pipeline-bucket-selector-aggregation.html) feature will help on filtering out the results.

Answer (score 1):

Try out this below search query:

```
{
  "aggs": {
    "sales_per_hour": {
      "date_histogram": {
        "field": "event_time",
        "fixed_interval": "1h",
        "format": "yyyy-MM-dd:HH:mm"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "sales_per_hour_per_product": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "name.keyword"
          },
          "aggs": {
            "the_filter": {
              "bucket_selector": {
                "buckets_path": {
                  "the_doc_count": "_count"
                },
                "script": "params.the_doc_count > 10"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**It will filter out all the documents, whose count is greater than 10 based on `"params.the_doc_count > 10"`**

Comment: @frédéric chantrel thanks for your feedback. It would be great if you can share some sample data and expected search result, so that I can provide a working example for you

Comment: @frédéric chantrel please don't forget to upvote and accept my answer, if it helped you in any way 

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your help this is not far from what i would like but not exactly ; with the bucket selector i have something like this :

```
"aggregations" : {
    "sales_per_hour" : {
      "buckets" : [
        {
          "key_as_string" : "2020-08-31:23:00",
          "key" : 1598914800000,
          "doc_count" : 16,
          "sales_per_hour_per_product" : {
          "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
          "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
          "buckets" : [
          {
              "key" : "my_product_1",
              "doc_count" : 2
          },
          {
              "key" : "my_product_2",
              "doc_count" : 2
          },
          {
              "key" : "myproduct_3",
              "doc_count" : 12
          }
        ]
      }
    }
    ]
}
```

And sometimes none of the buckets are greater than 10, is it possible to have the same thing but with the filter on _count applied to the second level aggregation (sales_per_hour_per_product) and not on the first level (sales_per_hour) ?